# Programmatically include a Facelet

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, facelets

My task is to programatically include a Facelet containing some EL and one or more composite components in JSF to another Facelet (if a condition is met), and I also want to do this **without** the `<ui:inclue />` tag.

My first shot was to use the following in a BodyRenderer in the encodeBegin method:

```
FaceletContext faceletContext = (FaceletContext)context.getAttributes().get(FaceletContext.FACELET_CONTEXT_KEY);
faceletContext.includeFacelet(component, "pages/newxhtml.xhtml");
```

But that gave an 404 like:

> HTTP Status 404 - /index.xhtml: /Applications/NetBeans/glassfish-4.0/glassfish/domains/domain1/generated/jsp/my-test-site/loader_1738428769/META-INF/resources/common/components/pages/newxhtml.xhtml(No such file or directory&#41

I'm feeling kind of stuck here and could really use some help to solve the task. My second question would be how I could load this Facelet from another jar file where it's placed under /META-INF/resources/common/...

Comment: Looks only like a path issue, have you tried a different path?

Comment: Yes I did, the path to the file (on the filesystem) is /my-test-site/src/main/webapp/pages/newxhtml.xhtml
Any clue?

Comment: What is the URL of the page you are openning when the code is executed?

Comment: http://localhost:8080/my-test-site/ and the file is placed under pages/newxhtml.xhtml when compiled to war

Comment: Uhm, I made a new project within netbeans that is using ant as build instead of maven and it seems to work with the setup that I described in my first post. Any ideas of what I could miss?